# JQuery create dynamic object array in each as one row

Tags: jquery

I have a function that can filter an object array (data) based on another (myFilter). That filter function works perfectly if the object array (myFilter) that it requires is in a wide format.  This works:

`[{ rep_name: "John", the_task: "Cold Call" }]`

The field name (rep_name) and value (John) come from dynamically added checkboxes. So I loop on checked checkboxes to build up the filter conditions in an attempt to build the object array required by the filtering function with the following:

```
$('.chk_filter').each(function (a, b) {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var f = $(this).data("field");
        var v = $(this).val();
        var item = {}
        item[f] = v;
        myFilter.push(item);      
    }
});
```

And this is the function that reduces the larger object array (has the same fields and values in the filter(s)):

```
data = data.filter(function (i) {
       return myFilter.some(function (j) {
       return !Object.keys(j).some(function (prop) {
              return i[prop] != j[prop];
              });
        });
 });
 console.log(data);
```

My problem is that when I build the object array in the JQuery each loop it pushes each object as rows. I get this:

`[{rep_name: "John"}, {the_task: "Cold Call"}`

when I need this:

`[{ rep_name: "John", the_task: "Cold Call" }]`

Hope someone can shed some light on formatting the object as above.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it should be:  move `var item = {};` to the line before the each-loop.  Move `arr_filter.push(item);` to the line after the each-loop.

Comment: In this case you are assigning individual `item` array(s) into the `arr_filter` array every loop action rather than just simply assigning key-value pairs into the `arr_filter`... Try out @JoeCoder suggestion and it should work in the way you want

Comment: Thanks both of you and Joe Coder, that worked!